# Compiling Boost on OS X 10.9 and link to own application

Tags: c++, boost, osx-mavericks

I have already read a lot of post, but I cannot understand how to compile boost library on OS X 10.9.4 in order to link it statically in my application.

I have Xcode 5 installed and also "Command Line Tools" installed.

I have download the ZIP archive of boost 1.56.0, bootstrapped with:

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/Users/foo/dev/lib/boost_1_56_0 --libdir=/Users/foo/dev/lib/boost_1_56_0/lib
```

Then installed with

```
./b2
```

But when I tried to compile a little test like the following:

```
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

int main(int, char*[])
{
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";


  return 0;
}
```

With:

```
clang logtest.cpp -I /Users/foo/lib/boost_1_56_0/include -L /Users/foo/lib/boost_1_56_0/lib
```

I got a lot of errors regarding the linking:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: 
"boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view::public_data::destroy(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view::public_data const*)", referenced from:
  boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record::reset() in logtest-d5345b.o
...
```

So I also tried to add the following parameters in the bootstrap:

```
cxxflags="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" address-model=32_64 threading=multi macos-version=10.9 stage
```

And the following to b2:

```
threading=multi link=static runtime-link=static cxxflags="-stdlib=libc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libc++"
```

But nothing changed...

So I'm looking for a guide that teach how I can compile from scratch the boost library and how I can compile an application that *links it*.

Comment: Have you considered installing Macports and installing boost using that?  It will save lots of work.

Comment: @trojanfoe I would like to avoid to depend on Macports or Brew, since I want to distribute my application (and source code) easily.

Comment: I don't see how using macports or brew changes that.

Answer (score 2):

In your build command you specified link directory, but didn't specify library you link your executable with. Add `-llibrary-name` to the command. I believe it should be

```
clang logtest.cpp -I /Users/foo/lib/boost_1_56_0/include -L /Users/foo/lib/boost_1_56_0/lib -lboost_log
```

Maybe, add other libraries `boost_log` depends on (`boost_log_setup` and `pthread` are good candidates).

For more information about linking boost libraries, refer to the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library).

Comment: Yes, for sure I was forgetting to specify the libraries name to be linked with, but anyway I still have the same problem with the following command: c++ logTest.cpp -I ../boost_1_56_0/include/ -L ../boost_1_56_0/lib/ -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_log -lboost_log_setup -lpthread (I have also tried on OS X 10.10 with Xcode 6, no GCC installed)

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you the example of code from my CMakeLists on Mac Os. It was used exactly for linking of boost logging library:

```
target_link_libraries(testq boost_system boost_thread boost_log boost_log_setup pthread)
```

Comment: Just as curiosity, how/where did you find the list of libraries to be linked with? Anyway, as you can see in my comment for Alex's answer, I still have problem with the linking process.